# I want to use this piece of code using java SE6 from java SE7

Tags: java, file-upload, file-io

I want to use this piece of code using java SE6 "Path fileName=Paths.get(filepath+filename)" which is supported in java SE 7. Tried a lot, didn't find any solution. Could any one suggest me in regarding.

Here are the piece of code which am using,

```
Path fileName=Paths.get(file +"\\"+ repName+"_"+tdate+".PDF");
...
private static void checkFileExist(Path filePath) {
    if (Files.exists(filePath)) {
        System.out.println("Filename: " + filePath.toString());
        System.out.println("Exist in location!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Filename: " + filePath.toString());
        System.out.println("Does not exist in location!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this which works in Java 6 and 7

```
File file = new File(dir, repName+"_"+tdate+".PDF");
...
private static void checkFileExist(File file) {
    System.out.println("Filename: " + file);
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Exist in location!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Does not exist in location!");
    }
}
```